# What does "Gai" of GaiException & EAI stand for / mean?

Tags: android

There's no javadoc. Can anyone help explain what exactly the "Gai" of GaiException means? As well as "EAI"?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/GaiException.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/abe10a6415358d66bb0d1ac3145c8909a327a54d/src/main/java/libcore/io/OsConstants.java

Answer (score 11):

Lines 22-27 of the [`GaiException.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/GaiException.java) file state the following:

> /**
>     An unchecked exception thrown when the {@link Os} **{@code getaddrinfo}** or {@code getnameinfo}
>    * methods fail. This exception contains the native error value, for comparison against the
>    * {@code GAI_} constants in {@link OsConstants}, should sophisticated
>    * callers need to adjust their behavior based on the exact failure.
>    */

Based on the wording `@code getaddrinfo`, it looks like it means **Get Address Information**.

---

**OS Interface**

The `getaddrinfo` method is defined in the [`Os.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/Os.java) interface file on line 50:

`public InetAddress[] getaddrinfo(String node, StructAddrinfo hints) throws GaiException;`

---

**OS Interface Implementations**

The `getaddrinfo` method is then implemented (via the Os interface) in [`ForwardingOs.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/ForwardingOs.java) on line 59:

```
public InetAddress[] getaddrinfo(String node, StructAddrinfo hints) throws GaiException {
    return os.getaddrinfo(node, hints);
}
```

The functionality from [`ForwardingOs.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/ForwardingOs.java) is then inherited by the [BlockGuardOs.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616012dc0d56c2da9af2b9b1183e76c7e044/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/BlockGuardOs.java) class (and is not overidden)